# Android - Wait for Volley response to complete and continue executing

Tags: android, android-volley

I need execute a Volley request and wait for the response to parse it and return it, but have no idea on how to achieve this. 
Can someone help?
here is my code :

```
public void getWord(){
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://ent-ifsi.com/Projet/Application_Android/pendu_android.php",
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject lesMots = response.getJSONObject("lesMots");

                        Iterator<?> keys = lesMots.keys();

                        while (keys.hasNext()) {
                            String key = (String) keys.next();
                            if (lesMots.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) lesMots.get(key);
                                //Récupération des deux mots, anglais et français
                                String wordToFind = obj.getString("wordFrench").toUpperCase();
                                String wordEnglish = obj.getString("wordEnglish").toUpperCase();
                                //Mots mis dans un array respectif

                                listOfWordEnglish.add(wordEnglish);
                                listOfWordFrench.add(wordToFind);
                                container.removeAllViews();
                            }
                            numberOfWord++;

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            },


            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley", "ERROR");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }


    );
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

There is 7 word in each array but when i'm trying to get acess into my initGame function, it said they are empty, i guess it's because volley request is not this fast !
if someone can explain me how to do that

here is my initGame function

```
`public void initGame() {
        win = false;
        found = 0;
        typed_word.setText("");
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.first);
        listOfLetters = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfWordFrench = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfWordEnglish = new ArrayList<>();
        getWord();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfWordEnglish.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            String wordEnglish = listOfWordEnglish.get(i);
            wordEnglishPendu.setText(wordEnglish);
            word = listOfWordFrench.get(i);
            for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {
                TextView oneLetter = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.textview, null);
                container.addView(oneLetter);

            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: is your request fired ? Is the ```onResponse``` called ?

Comment: i just called my `getWord()` into a function who must init my game, i just added my InitGame()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Volley` is asynchronous, so the `for` loop below `getWord()` will be called before `onResponse` of your Volley request.

The solution for your issue is to move that `for` loop into `onResponse`, there you can place it after the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank for help but if i do that, when i want to get a word and put it into a textview, i will always have to do the request right ? I only want to make one request when i launch the app :(

Comment: No, only one request, then after your global list have already values, you can access it somewhere, perhaps when you click on a button, for example.

Comment: That helped me, i made what u say but i write if my arraylist is empty then i launch my request, if not, i launch a other who only take word in array !